# how to save file as pdf from binary output using logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have `HTTP` output for body('HTTP') is -

```
    {"statusCode":200,"headers":{"dataserviceversion":"2.0","sap-metadata-last-modified":"Fri, 09 Aug 2019 10:41:57 GMT",
"Cache-Control":"no-store, no-cache","Date":"Fri, 
09 Aug 2019 11:26:58 GMT","Content-Type":"application/atom+xml; type=feed; charset=utf-8","Content-Length":"1365811"},
"body":{"$content-type":"application/atom+xml; type=feed; charset=utf-8","$content":"PGZlZWQgeG1sbn
```

> note - content-type is  application/atom+xml

$content is having binary data which is nothing but pdf file.

I want to get this data and convert it into pdf file

into sharepoint connector while create pdf file i send `body('HTTP')?['content']` still unable to create a valid pdf file. even tried only `body('HTTP')` same error.

[image]

while opening file it throws error - 
[image]

in sharepoint create file connector i'm passing that binary string like - `base64ToBinary(thatBinaryValue)` but in sharepoint type is

```
 "$content-type": "application/octet-stream",
```

[image]

Comment: @GeorgeChen updated question pls check

Comment: The content-type is application/octet-stream is because you are using the binary to create the pdf, If I use base64ToBinary to create it's application/octet-stream too.

Comment: Suppose it's your application/atom+xml problem, you need to parse it then use logic app to get it.

Comment: finally it works i modified the binary string which i was sending from HTTP :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried with HTTP trigger to process PDF, and I suppose it's caused by the content expression. If I use the `@triggerBody()['$content']` to process pdf content, the file couldn't be open too.

So I change it to `@triggerBody()` to get the content and it works, so yours should be just `body('HTTP')`. You could have a try, hope this could help you.

**Update**: I tried with HTTP action, and got the same result, it's the expression problem. So just change the expression.

Comment: Nope same error with body('HTTP') i already tried that :( 
I think we need to use something like base64ToBinary() bcoz i'm saving file into sharepoint .

Comment: I tried both application/atom+xml and application/pdf they all could process the file.

Comment: Yes. I use a blob pdf file link to test it.

Comment: This is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85zSW.png) and the [pdf preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckOFF.png) so it did could work.

Comment: my logic app is successful but when i download share point pdf file and open it.. it give above error popup :( is that because result is not correct ?

Comment: @Neo, if this could not work you could try with `base64ToBinary(body('HTTP')['$content'])`, this way I test it works.

Comment: And what you got use `body('HTTP')`?

Comment: in body i got all this - 
{"statusCode":200,"headers":{"dataserviceversion":"2.0","sap-metadata-last-modified":"Fri, 09 Aug 2019 10:41:57 GMT","Cache-Control":"no-store, no-cache","Date":"Fri, 09 Aug 2019 11:26:58 GMT","Content-Type":"application/atom+xml; type=feed; charset=utf-8","Content-Length":"1365811"},"body":{"$content-type":"application/atom+xml; type=feed; charset=utf-8","$content":"PGZlZWQgeG1sbn

Comment: @Neo, I guess it's caused by the content type, I tried to change blob content type however it only change the x-ms-meta-ContentType, the body content-type is still application/pdf, I suppose you need to use `base64ToBinary(body('HTTP')['$content'])`, this will only need the content whatever the content type is.

Comment: Would you mind share me your http link, let me have a test.

Comment: unfortunately http will not work outside my firewall network :(